# Download Facebook Page's Posts By Others

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have successfully been able to download my own posts on a Facebook Page with all the comments, shares and likes info using Facebook's Graph API. However, I am unable to do that when the fans are posting on the page. In the page it's call "Posts By Others". What is the URL to download these using Graph API?

Thanks!

Cyril

Comment: This is what they call Posts done on Page's Timeline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I download my own posts by this:

facebookPageID/posts/

Now I will have to use this in order to download posts by others.

facebookPageID/feed/